# SignalR 1.1.2 not working properly?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am using SignalR 1.1.2 with the following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js") %>" ></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.2.min.js") %>"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message. 
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.Others.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I check this on different browsers. On some browsers it works and some browsers does not respond.

Comment: your jquery is old, not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: @Snoopy, tested with Latest Jquery Doesn't work

Comment: you need to expand on this. What browsers doesnt it work on? Have you tried examining the output of fiddler to see whats different with a working scenario ?

Comment: I have tested in Chrome and FF. It's not working there. Can you test this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @KiranChalla, Not sure? But chating is not working. Can you please test this? This is sample coming from asp.net site. Is this sample not work with 2.1.2?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that could be causing a connection to silently fail. If you don't have a meaningful error message, see the first chapter of this document for some
potential causes:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting